# Can OpenVPN use an existing tunnel device instead of dynamically creating a new one?

Tags: networking, openvpn

I wondered, if the following scenario is possible:

If I create a new tunnel adapter on startup of my ubuntu server 14.04, can I tell an OpenVPN client to use this tunnel instead of creating a new tunnel for itself?

The thought behind this is that I could allow a normal user to create an OpenVPN connection through said client without giving root privileges needed to create the tunnel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the OpenVPN manual page:

> --dev tunX | tapX | null
>
> TUN/TAP virtual network device ( X can be omitted for a dynamic
>   device.)

---

Create a persistent tunnel device with:

```
sudo openvpn --mktun --dev <tun-name> --user <user-name> --group <group-name>
```

`<tun-name>` will be the tunnel device name. It should be "tun+number" (`tun0`, `tun1`, etc.).

`<user-name>` and `<group-name>` refer to user that will own the tunnel device.

Then you should use the same tunnel device name in the OpenVPN client. Instead of using `--dev tun` (command line parameter) or `dev tun` (configuration file), you should specify the name of the persistent tunnel device you created: `--dev <tun-name>` (command line parameter) or `dev <tun-name>` (configuration file).

Comment: When I try to use `--dev RemoteBackupTunnel` it will just respond with "I don't recognize RemoteBackupTunnel as a tun or tap service". Same with other names except tun (+ a number). `--dev tun10` for instance works fine.

Comment: @FlorianSplett Indeed. It's weird, because I could swear I have used other names a long time ago. Or maybe it's my memory that's failing. Answer fixed.

Comment: Use `dev-type tun` in this case.